# Making a progress bar from a javascript counter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a javascript function which gets time from a function. Its like a counter starting from 00:00 and goes on to a fixed time. The timer can be paused/resumed with a button. And it works fine.

The javascript function gives time elapsed and total time!

Now I have two CSS:

```
#seek-bg and #seek-bar
```

I want to move the seek-bar on seek-bg horizontally. Is it possible to do so without jquery?

How can I connect the timer and these CSS?

**Code!**

```
#seek-bg {
    height:3px;
    background-color:black;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
}

#seek-bar{
    background-color:white;
    width:4px;
    height:3px;
}
```

Comment: You have `time elapsed` and `total time` so do some maths and make a percentage. Your `#seek-bg` is `100px` wide so make the `#seek-bar` the percentage obtained from time and ta da. Obviously you will need to JavaScript but jQuery itself is of course optional.

Comment: can you give the js you are using? (or better make a fiddle?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to move the seek-bar on seek-bg horizontally. Is it possible to
>   do so without jquery?

Yes it is possible. Take a look at HTML5 progress bar:

```
<progress value="10" max="100"></progress>
```

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-progress-bar/

[**DEMO**](http://demo.hongkiat.com/html5-progress-bar/)